# OpenNTF Domino API 4.0.0 - Logging: Couldn't initialize from PropertyFile; activating fallback

Tags: lotus-domino

I'm getting the message "Logging: Couldn't initialize from PropertyFile; activating fallback ..." on a fresh install of Domino 9.0.1 FP8 with the latest OpenNTF Domino API 4.0.0. There's another question with the same issue, but the solution was a fresh install.

After the Domino install we created the updatesite.nsf, imported the OpenNTF Domino API 4.0.0. Clicked, Action, Sign All Content, then added the **OSGI_HTTP_DYNAMIC_BUNDLES=updateSite.nsf** to the notes.ini and rebooted the server.

With a little more digging it seems the **IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT/org.openntf.domino.logging.logconfig.properties** file is missing from the OpenNTF install or not being created.

There are no applications running on this server, other than the basic Domino default applications you would have from a fresh install.

Also, this isn't a fresh re-install. This is a brand new Win 2008 R2 server with a new Domino 9.0.1 FP8 install.